# How to transfer several rows from one table to other table (SQL)

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` with colums `id`, `login`, `pass`. Also I have a php array: `$array = [1,3,5]`. How can I transfer rows from `TableA` to `TableB` where `id` equal each value of my array? `id` is autoincremented and must be unique.
In my head it looks like this :

```
INSERT INTO TableB (`login`, `pass`) 
SELECT `login`, `pass` FROM TableA WHERE `id` = $array[0] 
AND `id` = $array[1] AND `id` = $array[2];
```

But it does not work

Is there any chances to do it in cycle using `WHILE`?

Comment: Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Your id can't have multiple values *at the same time*, try `WHERE \`id\` IN (1,3,5)` (obviously using your array here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a statement such as this:

```
$ids = [1,3,5];
$query = "INSERT INTO `TableB` (`login`, `pass`) SELECT `login`,`pass` FROM `TableA` WHERE `id` IN (".implode(",", $ids).");";
```

Although: You should be using prepared statements and parameters for this, this answer is just meant to show the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy let's say you are using mysqli:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM TableA limit 3";
//takes first 3 rows from TableA
//$con being the connection string in config file
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//takes each row by row
$username = $row['username'];
$password = $row['password'];
//now that we initiated variables the sql query
$query1 = "INSERT INTO TableB (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
mysqli_query($con,$query1);
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:
I just read that it should have an array so you should change your query to this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count(array), $i++){

$query= "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID = '$array[i]'";

//$con being the connection string in config file
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
//takes each row by row
$username = $row['username'];
$password = $row['password'];
//now that we initiated variables the sql query
$query1 = "INSERT INTO TableB (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
mysqli_query($con,$query1);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code has unclosed bracers (the `while`-line) and strings (the password column in the query).

Comment: Thanx for answer!